# New footer help and Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, design

Two questions:

- Why are there Stack Exchange sites at all in the footer? We have a header drop-down menu button already, I am using it to visit other communities, and I'll use it when I need to find one. I will never use the footer for this. Point of duplicating? Categories? Easier to discover?
- Help. I just discovered there is a help in the footer. Good. Now I will be able to finally find those help links when I need them (I was using Google to do so since the new header). But why is it in the footer? Because help is not important and it shouldn't be visible in header all time?

Comment: Note that there is also a link to Help in the drop down menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why are there Stack Exchange sites at all in the footer?

This is part of site graduation. People like seeing their favourite sites there. It also gives these sites more exposure (not least from search engines - who wouldn't be opening up the communities drop down).

> But why is it in the footer? Because help is not important and it shouldn't be visible in header all time?

Help exists in the header for **low rep** users - it gets replaced by the review icon for users who have the access review queues privilege, the thinking being that by this time, most users are not is as much need of header access to help. This is one reason the link is in the footer - the other is that many sites do put a help link in the footer and may people expect it there.

Comment: Ok, it seems like my personal issue, I am simply not used to the footer concept. I realized that after reading your answer, thanks.

Comment: "People like seeing their favourite sites there." [citation-required] In all seriousness, given the recent redesign of the footer, do you guys actually have data that shows users *use* the footer to navigate to other sites? I've never used it even once, but it wouldn't be the first time I was weird. Or is having everything in the footer all about SEO?

Comment: @CodyGray - thousands of clicks from the footer to different network sites every day.